# Find all missing Numbers using one SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server

The data looks like

```
[Month]     [Date]
---------------
201306      1
201306      2
201306      5
201306      6
201306      7
201307      1
201307      4
201307      6
201309      1
201309      2
```

How to find all missing Dates by Month?

Here is the expected results

```
[Month]     [Date]
---------------
201306      3
201306      4
201307      2
201307      3
201307      5
```

Comment: You need a calendar table having all possible dates. Then do NOT EXISTS or NOT IN, or EXCEPT.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think does it and pretty efficiently

```
declare @T table (yy int, dd int);
insert into @T values  
       (201306, 1)
     , (201306, 2)
     , (201306, 5)
     , (201306, 6)
     , (201306, 7)
     , (201307, 1)
     , (201307, 4)
     , (201307, 6)
     , (201309, 1)
     , (201309, 2);
with cte as 
( select yy, min(dd) + 1 as mn, max(dd) as mx 
  from @T 
  group by yy 
  having min(dd) + 1 < max(dd)
  union all 
  select c.yy, c.mn + 1, c.mx 
  from cte c
  where c.mn  + 1 < c.mx 
)
select yy, mn as dd 
from cte 
except 
select yy, dd 
from  @T t
order by yy, mn;

yy          dd
----------- -----------
201306      3
201306      4
201307      2
201307      3
201307      5
```

Comment: @MtwStark I think it is fixed

Answer (score 1):

You would need some kind of `lookup` tables which could has intermediate dates and use `cross join` with `left join` to find missing dates

*First* *thought*

```
;with cte as (
      select min(date) mdate, max(date) mxdate from table
      union all
      select mdate+1 as mdate,  mxdate
      from cte c
      where c.mdate < c.mxdate
)

select distinct t.Month, c.mdate 
from table t cross join (select mdate from cte) c
left join table t1 on t1.month = t.Month and t1.date = c.mdate
where t1.date is null
```

*Second* *thought*

```
;with cte as (
      select  month, min(date) over (partition by month) mdate, max(date) over (partition by month) mxdate 
      from sample t union all
      select month, mdate+1 as mdate,  mxdate
      from cte c
      where c.month = month and c.mdate < c.mxdate
)

select c.month, c.mdate 
from cte c left join sample t1 
           on t1.month = c.Month and t1.date = c.mdate
where t1.date is null
group by c.month, c.mdate
```

[Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/63bad/3)

Comment: @MtwStark... No, it seems op has kind of typo.

Comment: with op input data, your output gives 201307-7, 201309-3, 4, 5, 6 and 7, all wrong results

Comment: @MtwStark.. All are done My first thought might be wrong, but i edited with what the op want to achieve.  Btw, Thanks for pointing out to me.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using a recursive query

```
with rndata as
(
  select row_number() over (partition by mon order by d) rn, * from data
), rcte as
(
  select mon, d, (select max(d) from data where data.mon = rndata.mon) max_d
  from rndata where rn = 1
  union all
  select rcte.mon, rcte.d + 1, rcte.max_d
  from rcte
  where rcte.d + 1 < max_d
)
select mon, d 
from rcte
where not exists (
  select 1
  from data 
  where rcte.mon = data.mon and
             rcte.d = data.d
)
```

[dbfiddle demo](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=8ca62725d9ac19979e7acefbd1e940a2)

Answer (score 0):

Consider using below approach.

```
CREATE TABLE #Date([Month] int, [Date] int)

INSERT INTO #Date 
VALUES(201306, 1)
    ,(201306, 2)
    ,(201306, 5)
    ,(201306, 6)
    ,(201306, 7)
    ,(201307, 1)
    ,(201307, 4)
    ,(201307, 6)
    ,(201309, 1)
    ,(201309, 2)

;WITH CTE AS 
    (
        SELECT
        *,LEAD([Date]) OVER(ORDER BY [Month],[Date]) AS NextDate
        FROM #Date d
    )
    SELECT 
        d.[Month], m.Dt AS [Date]
    FROM CTE d
    CROSS APPLY(    SELECT v.Dt 
                    FROM 
                        (VALUES(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10),(11)
                                ,(11),(12),(13),(14),(15),(16),(17),(18),(19),(20)
                                ,(21),(22),(23),(24),(25),(26),(27),(28),(29),(30),(31)
                        ) AS v(Dt)
                    WHERE v.Dt > d.Date AND v.Dt < d.NextDate
                ) m
```

The only limitation this approach has is, it is not able to find missing days that falls before first date.

Answer (score 0):

This is a fast but still simple solution:

1) use `sys.sysobjects` as tally table to gett all dates in each month.
2) calc min/max range for each month to keep only gaps inside the range.
3) join tally and range to get expected dates for each month, and left join   your table to math existing dates.
4) filter in `WHERE` condition only missing dates

```
declare @T table ([month] int, [date] int);
insert into @T values  
       (201306, 1)
     , (201306, 2)
     , (201306, 5)
     , (201306, 6)
     , (201306, 7)
     , (201307, 1)
     , (201307, 4)
     , (201307, 6)
     , (201309, 1)
     , (201309, 2);

with
n as (select top 31 ROW_NUMBER() over (order by id) n from sys.sysobjects),
r as (select [month], MIN([date]) dd1, MAX([date]) dd2 from @t group by [month])
select r.[month], n [date]
from r
join n on n between dd1 and dd2
left join @T t on n.N = t.[date] and r.[month] = t.[month]
where dd2<>dd1 and t.[date] is null
order by r.[month], n
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use numbers/Tally table approach like below:
<kbd>**[See live demo](http://rextester.com/YNCUT77344)**</kbd>

```
create table sample ([Month] int,      [Date] int)
insert into sample values 
(201306, 1)
,(201306, 2)
,(201306, 5)
,(201306, 6)
,(201306, 7)
,(201307, 1)
,(201307, 4)
,(201307, 6)
,(201309, 1)
,(201309, 2);

; with daysinmonth as 
(
    select * from
    (
        values
         (1,31),(2,28),(3,31),(4,30),(5,31),(6,30),
         (7,31),(8,31),(9,30),(10,31),(11,30),(12,31)
        ) v(m,d)

    )

select [month], dd 
from sample 
cross apply 
(
    select top 
        (
                select  d from
                daysinmonth 
                where m=cast( right(cast([Month] as varchar(6)),2) as int)
           )
    row_number() over ( order by (select null)) dd
    from
    sys.tables t1 cross join
    sys.tables t2 
  )  c
where [date]<>dd
```